# Losing query string on redirect from https to http

Tags: asp.net, https

I have a site https:// www.mysite.com that runs completely using HTTPS (I redirect http to https in IIS). This all works fine.

I have an old version of the site http:// old.mysite.com which some users are still running on that is running over HTTP only. This all works fine.

There is 1 URL that my new site redirects (using a Response.Redirect in the global.asax) to my old site. For example the user requests https:// www.mysite.com/page.aspx?query=string and I redirect them to the old site http:// old.mysite.com/page.aspx?query=string. The redirect works well except that the query string is missing when it gets to the old site.

The URL that I have to redirect comes from a url embedded at customer sites, so I can't just update them all to point to the old site. I tested and this all works fine when I run my new site under HTTP so the transfer is HTTP to HTTP, but it fails when I do HTTPS to HTTP.

Any ideas on what the problem is?

Thanks,
Jim

Comment: Jim does it make a difference if you did a permanent redirect instead of just a re-direct? Also, during debugging, do you see the query string parameter values (when using https)? This is not an answer but maybe you should respond with a page letting users know yo update their books marks?

Comment: Hi Shiv, thanks for the comment. I am actually doing it by adding a temporary redirect 302 to the header (although Response.Redirect didn't work either). In a month or two the users will be migrated off of the old site and the URL will be valid again. As for debugging I know that the redirect url includes the query string on the new site, but when I print the request url & query string to the page on the old site (for testing) I only see the url.

Answer (score 2):

Alright I got it figured out so I'll post in case anyone else hits the issue. I was using the HTTP Redirect module in IIS 7 to redirect any HTTP traffic to HTTPS for my new website. For the url to redirect to I just had 'https://www.mysite.com'. I found some variables that you can add to the redirect url to keep the query string. So once I updated it to 'https://www.mysite.com$S$Q' it worked.